# How to check usage of Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have an Android app which uses Firebase storage which in turn uses Google cloud storage.
How do I check my usage limits in either Firebase / Google cloud console.

I'm not able to locate any options in either Firebase console or Google cloud storage.

How can I locate storage usage for my app?

Comment: The current Firebase console now possible to display your usages.